# Can't apply custom theme in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, themes

has anybody tried to install a custom theme in Magento 2?. I’m trying to apply my custom theme in Magento 2 so i can start testing, but i don’t know from where to start really. The file structure is totally different, i can’t make Magento 2 to take my theme files.
Can anybody guide me a bit?, it will be really appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: i just searched magento official site. could not find magento 2, is it the version you are talking anout right??

Comment: Yes, Magento 2. Take a look here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/category/magento-2/                            You can download the dev version here:https://github.com/magento/magento2

Comment: Are you trying to install a Magento 1.x theme to a Magento 2 instance?  The theme will have to be properly converted to Magento 2's file structure.

Comment: Yes i know, that's my question. How the theme must be converted??

Answer (score 0):

To make theme working please copy theme.xml and media folder from app/design/frontend/Magento/blank and make relative changes about theme.
Hope it works for you to start the theming.

Answer (score 0):

Create Theme Directory

To create a directory for your Magento 2 theme, you need to go: /app/design/frontend. Under frontend directory, create a new directory according to your theme vendor name: /app/design/frontend/themename (I choose  for my themename vendor name) under your theme vendor directory, create a directory for your Magento 2 theme: /app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme.

After creating this structure, you need to declare your Magento 2 theme so that Magento system knows it exists and you can set your theme as a current theme in your Magento 2 backend.

Declare your Magento 2 theme

Now you need to create the theme.xml file under app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/theme.xml and use the code below:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd"> <title>m2-theme</title> <parent>Magento/Luma</parent> <media> <preview_image>media/m2-theme-image.jpg</preview_image> </media> </theme>
```

In  tag insert the name of your theme, and in the  tag you can specify parent theme for fallback purposes. I am using the Luma theme.

In the  tag I declare a theme image. This is a thumbnail image which shows in the Magento 2 admin on our theme page so we can see a preview of what our theme looks like. Thumbnail image is located in app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/media/m2-theme-image.jpg. Make sure you have this thumbnail in the correct location. If you don’t have this file in the correct location, you will get an error when you visit your theme page in Magento 2 admin.

Make Your Magento 2 Theme a Composer package

Add a composer.json file in your theme directory: app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/composer.json to register the package on a packaging server. This file is provided in the theme dependency information. Magento default public packaging server is https://packagist.org/. Use this following code:

```
{     "name": "Themename/m2-theme",     "description": "N/A",     "require": {         "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",         "Themename/m2-theme": "100.0.*",         "magento/framework": "100.0.*"     },     "type": "magento2-theme",     "version": "100.0.1",     "license": [         "OSL-3.0",         "AFL-3.0"     ],     "autoload": {         "files": [             "registration.php"         ]     } }
```

Add registration.php to register your Magento 2 theme

To register your theme in the Magento system, you need to create registration.php file in your theme directory: app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/registration.php and use the following code in your registration.php:

```
<?php /**  * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */ \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,   'frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme',     __DIR__ );
```

Directory Structure in Magento 2

After complete theme declaration and registration, you need to create the directory structure for your theme layout, styles and template files. Below, you can see how your theme directory should look like. I am using my own Vendor and directory name.

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/theme.xml

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/registration.php

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/composer.json

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/media

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/media/m2-theme-image.jpg

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/web

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/web/css

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/web/css/source

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/web/css/fonts

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/web/css/images

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/web/css/js

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/etc

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/etc/view.xml

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/Magento_Theme

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/Magento_Theme/layout

/app/design/frontend/Themename/m2-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

The web folder will be created where our theme’s CSS, js, fonts and images is located. If Magento 2 doesn’t have a skin folder, these files go in here.

We have created view.xml file under the etc directory, with the view.xml file. We configure the Magento 2 Catalog images size and other things.

Apply and Configure theme in Magento 2 Admin

After adding your theme to the file system, everything is ready for you to activate your theme and apply it to your store. Go to Magento 2 backend, then go to Content > Design > Themes. And make your sure your theme appears on this list.

When you can see your theme in this list, go to Stores > Configuration > Design, select your newly created theme

Answer (score 0):

The structure of Magento 2 theme is surely different.

Firstly, create a new theme directory in app/design/frontend.

Secondly, declare the new theme by:

- Creating theme.xml: this file identifies the name, parent and other basic info of the new theme.
- Creating Composer.json: this file is used to install the theme via Composer later.
- Creating registration.php: this file is required in any Magento 2 Extension and Themes.
- Creating static files directories: this folder is used to store CSS, JS, image files.
- Creating logo folder: this folder contains files that determine the location and size of your new theme logo.

Thirdly, apply and configure theme in admin:
 - Run Upgrade Command.
 - Apply the theme.
 - Deploy.

For more detailed tutorial, go to [Guide to create Magento 2 theme](https://bssthemes.com/blog/create-magento-2-theme/).